# Visual Studio 2017 can't open "SDL.h" even though I added the include directory to the project

Tags: c, visual-studio, compilation, sdl-2

*I have tried answers from similarly asked question and non has not fix this problem.* I downloaded a fresh install of Visual Studio 2017 and the SDL2 development libraries. Then loaded up some sample code to open a window using SDL to test and then added the include directory containing all the SDL header files, as well as added the "SDL2.lib and SDL2main.lib". However Every-time I try to build the code it spits out several errors at me. I have also include some screen shots. Any help would be much appreciated. 
[This shows where the include directory is located and that it's is added to additional include.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxSb8.png) [This shows all the errors after building.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Udsc.png)

## The sample window code

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    SDL_Window *window;                    // Declare a pointer

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);              // Initialize SDL2

                                           // Create an application window with the following settings:
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "An SDL2 window",                  // window title
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial x position
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,           // initial y position
        640,                               // width, in pixels
        480,                               // height, in pixels
        SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL                  // flags - see below
    );

    // Check that the window was successfully created
    if (window == NULL) {
        // In the case that the window could not be made...
        printf("Could not create window: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    // The window is open: could enter program loop here (see SDL_PollEvent())

    SDL_Delay(3000);  // Pause execution for 3000 milliseconds, for example

                      // Close and destroy the window
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    // Clean up
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

### The errors

- E1696 cannot open source file "SDL.h"
- E0020 identifier "SDL_Window" is undefined
- E0020 identifier "Window" is undefined
- E0020 identifier "SDL_INIT_VIDEO" is undefined
- E0020 identifier "SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED" is undefined
- E0020 identifier "SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL" is undefined
- C1083 Cannot open include file:'SDL.h':No such file or directory

Comment: The screen shots show, the .h files in question are located below the "release" tree. You most likely try to build the debug version, don't you?

Comment: The image says "Release" and "Active(win32)": That hints at Release mode not being the active build setting. Also, I would add include directories to the project setting and not for an individual source code.

Comment: Yeah I'm building in debug. When I tried to build in release just now however it gave me a error lnk1561

Comment: Sorry I fixed that screen shot, I don't know why it was showed set to release in the image. The long list of errors popup when I build in debug, but when I build in release it gives me error lnk1561.

Comment: *lnk1561* is a linker error. If you got that far, then headers were included and declarations were found. My guess is that you need to tell linker which .lib files to use with your compiled object files to produce the final executable.

Comment: As i remember I was having the same problem when i was using windows, i solved it by changing the SDK from windows 8.1 to windows 10... from properties and this problem caused by my visual studio installer downloaded both SDK's but seems like 8.1 was default and incomplete whenever i start new c/c++ project

Answer (score 1):

So first I kept building in debug which gave me problems, the solution is to build release. Then with the lnk1561 I had to tell linker which .lib files to use with the compiled object, then add this "SDL2.lib;
SDL2main.lib;" without quotes to input additional dependencies, then finally add to system subsystem "Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)". Better explanation can be seen on this page... 
http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/windows/msvsnet2010u/index.php
Thank you everyone for your help!